# Representation of a finite group and its Sylow $p$-subgroup

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with order $|G|=p^n \cdot m$ for some positive integers $n,m$ and $H$ be a *Sylow $p$-subgroup* of $G$. What relations can we say about the representations of $G$ and $H$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "are they equivalent representations" mean?

Comment: "equivalent representations" was just an example. By equivalent representations, I mean the following: If there are representations $\rho_1:G \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ and $\rho_2:G \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ we say that they are equivalent if there exists an element $T \in GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ such that $\rho_{1}(g)=T.\rho_{2}(g)T^{-1}$

Comment: Oh, it seems like my example is wrong since equivalent representations are the representations of the same group. I'm editing the question.

Comment: Your edited question still does not make sense. What does conjugation do to a map? And how could this make it a map with a different domain?

Comment: Okay, I totally deleted my example, I will give a clear example if we can't get any answers. My bad.

Comment: As stands now, the question is way too broad to allow any reasonable answer.